# Migrating from ruby to jruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I am migrating from ruby-2.5.7 to jruby-9.2.12.0, when I run `bundle install` after the changing `ruby-version & gemfile` I get an error in pg-gem.

```
Installing pg 1.2.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/kush/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.12.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
/Users/kush/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.12.0/bin/jruby -I
/Users/kush/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.12.0/lib/ruby/stdlib -r
./siteconf20200707-6808-16ipijl.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
RuntimeError: The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
You have to install development tools first.

try_do at
/Users/kush/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.12.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:456
try_link0 at
/Users/kush/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.12.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:541
try_link at
/Users/kush/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.12.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:556
     <main> at extconf.rb:40
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

I have already installed developer-tools & also have Xcode in my mac.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pg` gem is highly specific to MRI (that is the "standard" ruby) and is not compatible with JRuby. As such, you should use a different database adapter here.

The most commonly used adapters in JRuby are [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) based. There are wrappers available for JRuby for most database database types. To use the PostgreSQL adapter used with Rails, you can use it with the `activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter` gem. For that, replace the

```
gem "pg"
```

line on your `Gemfile` with

```
gem "activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter"
```

See https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/blob/master/README.md for configuration and usage details.